# sending DHCPINFORM message from non-DHCP client

Tags: security, networking, dhcp

Suppose I have static ip in a subnet that has DHCP server. If i gonna send DHCPINFORM
message to the server, what will happen ?

amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per RFC-2131 tropic 4.3.5 for DHCPINFORM message:

"The DHCP server responds to a DHCPINFORM message by sending a DHCPACK message directly to the address given in the 'ciaddr' field of the DHCPINFORM message. The server MUST NOT send a lease expiration time to the client and SHOULD NOT fill in 'yiaddr'. The server includes
other parameters in the DHCPACK message as defined in section 4.3.1. "

**1.
Since a "DHCPAck" message does not mandate to add all requested network configuration parameters, a DHCP server is free to respond to a "DHCPInform" message, with/without requested parameter responses (implementation dependent), provided the client's static ip settings are validated under dhcp server pools.**

**2. 
Also, the dhcp-client may receive "DHCPAck" messages from many DHCP servers in response to its "DHCPInform" message. The client need to filters all of the "DHCPAck" messages received from DHCP servers to extract response parameters.**

[ Example:  The dhcp-client may searches each received "DHCPAck" message for a predetermined vendor-specific tag. If a "DHCPAck" message includes a predetermined vendor-specific tag, the dhcp-client extracts response parameters from this message. ]

Comment: I think there are flaws in this answer. Re 1: I believe there has to be a set of minimum parameters returned by the DHCP server; if there weren't DHCPINFORM would be *pointless*. Re 2: Maybe... but AFAIK, DHCP don't pass through routers, and there are protocols that preclude multi DHCP servers from running amok. Its not unbridled chaos!

Answer (score 0):

###### The question:

> If I send a DHCPINFORM message to the server, what will happen ?

Good question :)  The answer is not quite so clear. There are variances in DHCP server implementations, and the RFCs are a *bit ambiguous*. Additionally, the DHCPINFORM message (always initiated by the client) has gone through some revisions - or revelations if you prefer, and so the answer may also depend on the vintage of your DHCP server software:

DHCPINFORM was initially defined in [RFC2131](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131) in March, 1997. RFC2131 has been updated 4 times by: [3396](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3396), [4361](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4361), [5494](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5494), [6842](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6842). Since RFC 2131's publication, `DHCPINFORM` itself has subsequently been [*"clarified"* 7 times through 2011](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dhc-dhcpinform-clarify-06). A [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=IETF+%22DHCPINFORM%22&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web) will highlight some of the confusion sown in the wake of the creation of the `DHCPINFORM` message; [for example](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/dhcwg/QpgC747u9RZb8kqaUM4mE_LJX9w/).

A bit more recently, [RFC 3203](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3203) created a FORCERENEW message which forces the client (incl.  hosts using the DHCPINFORM message) to the RENEW state. [RFC 6704](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6704) updates RFC 3203 with details on use of the `Nonce Authentication` protocol for security. These standards have made the answer to your question still more ambiguous.

Due to variances in DHCP server implementations, perhaps the best way to answer your question is to use `nmap` (or similar) to discover the contents of the `ACK` message issued by your server in response to a `DHCPINFORM`. I chose `nmap` to illustrate this because of the `dhcp-discover` script that is part of the [`nmap scripting engine`](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/scripts/dhcp-discover.nse) sends a `DHCPINFORM` message. Here's how it worked on my system:

```bash
$ sudo nmap -sU -p 67 --script=dhcp-discover 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-30 18:37 CDT
Nmap scan report for myprivlan.com (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.0013s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
67/udp open  dhcps
| dhcp-discover:
|   DHCP Message Type: DHCPACK
|   Server Identifier: 192.168.1.1
|   Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
|   Router: 192.168.1.1
|   Domain Name Server: 192.168.1.1
|_  Domain Name: myprivlan.com
MAC Address: 00:25:B0:E0:A9:F5 

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.51 seconds
```

And so you can see what information was included in the server's `ACK` message. AIUI, this information may only be a subset of the complete set of information in the `ACK` message - a subset defined in the `dhcp-discover` script; you may analyze the script code to verify that.

As a further experiment, I made some changes to my DHCP server's configuration (the [OPNsense](https://opnsense.org/) firewall), and re-ran the same `nmap` command. In each case, the change I made on the server was accurately reflected in the `nmap` output.

Consequently, it seems that `DHCPINFORM` does meet the original objective - to update clients with static ip configurations. But it is the client's responsibility to request this update periodically.